# Replace a match in string using regex

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have the following String below

```
REQUEST DATA : uri=/XXX/XXXX;payload={"creditCardNumber": "PPPPP","expirationDate": "PPPP","transactionAmount": "164.7","arrivalDate": "08/17/2018","departureDate": "08/24/2018","merchantNumber": "MMMMMM","terminalId": "TTTT","userId": "UUUUU","clientTransactionId": "TTTTTT","applicationName": "AAA","bankCode": "AAAA","industryName": "RRRR","partialAuthorizationRequest": "N","addressVerificationData": "DDDDD"]
```

I would like to replace the value of creditCardNumber from "PPPPP" to "XXXX".
I wrote the following code but it was replacing everything including the String creditCardNumber which is not what I want.

```
    String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re2="(\"creditCardNumber\")";    // Double Quote String 1
    String re3="(:)";   // Any Single Character 1
    String re4="(\\s+)";    // White Space 1
    String re5="(\".*?\")"; // Double Quote String 2

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String string1=m.group(1);
        String c1=m.group(2);
        String ws1=m.group(3);
        String string2=m.group(4);
        String replacement = string1.toString() + c1.toString() + ws1.toString() + string2.toString();
        String finalReplacement = message.replaceFirst(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 ,"XXXXXXXXX");
        this.logger.debug(finalReplacement);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `(?<="creditCardNumber"\s{0,1000}:\s{0,1000}")[^"]*`

Comment: A simple find `("creditCardNumber"\s*:\s*)("PPPPP")` replace `$1"XXXX"` should work, have you tried it ? If the PPPPP is a variable clause like `[^"]`, capturing it will let you know what it _was_.

Comment: I used "PPP" and those random characters it's because it's confidential data. So the expression you gave me won't work if the value is changes. tnx @sln

Comment: It will work, just use your variable expression instead of `"PPPPP"`. I didn't mean try it _literally_. If it's an actual number regex, just put it here.

Comment: @joel with slight changes to sln's regex you can use `("creditCardNumber"\s*:\s*")[^"]*` and replace it with `$1XXXX`

Comment: `[^"]*` doesn't guarantee a closing ", just add it to the end, which would make the replacement look funky with just a closing "

Comment: @ctwheels I tired you suggestion using sln's regex  but it's replacing "creditCardNumber" to "XXXX". I would like to replace only the value of creditCardNumber. tnx

Comment: @ctwheels I was able to make it work using your first answer. Tnx